# JBoss Binding IP addresses

Tags: java, tomcat, binding, jboss, jira

I need some help from someone who understands JBoss Hostname Binding.  I think the solution is easy, although it's complicated to explain.

I am deploying an application using JBoss (v4.2) and am having troubles configuring the application.

This application has two parts, a web site on port 8080 and web services on port 8080 using SOAP APIs.

My server sits behind a firewall, and has an alias, let's say it's called **orange**.mycompany.com

My problem is that I cannot get the console to connect to the web services.  The website works, but I see an connection refused error connecting to the web services.

> [xfire.transport.http.HttpChannel]
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection
>   refused

There are 2 things I can control, the bind IP on Tomcat, and the URL of the web services.

If I start JBoss, and bind to the local IP address:

```
./run.sh -b 10.1.2.3
```

And I set the URL of the web services to be that same IP

```
url=http://10.1.2.3:8080/services
```

I can see the website on port 8080 from outside the firewall, but the console cannot connect to webservices.
From the server, orange, itself I cannot see the website by calling http://localhost:8080/ or http://10.1.2.3:8080 or orange.mycompany.com:8080

However, if I start JBoss and bind to 127.0.0.1:

```
./run.sh -b 127.0.0.1
```

And I set the URL of the web services to localhost

```
url=http://localhost:8080/services
```

Now I can't see the website at all from outside the firewall.
But from the server itself, I can see the website browsing http://localhost:8080 and the I can successfully connect to the web services.  That's great, but I need the website to be accessible from outside.

Can anyone suggest any combination of settings that will let me browse the website and also let the console call webservices on localhost?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Never mind.

Start JBoss binding to all IP's works.

```
./run.sh -b 0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Aren't your running JIRA standalone, right?

I always run tomcat and jboss behind a apache with mod_jk. This still hide ports, what sounds great for newbies users.

Your server is behind a NAT?

Sometimes I use ProxyPass or RewriteRules (mod_rewrite) to provide external access, thru reverse proxy.

Comment: Yes, I am running JIRA, as well as 3 other apps on the same instance of JBoss ( using port 8080 ).  Just to complicate things, I am also running a second instance of JBoss on port 80.

Comment: Ops, any app require to know where IP or host it's running? This sounds bad!

Even build "HTML elements", like "a", "img" etc, with complete URL (proto://host.domain:port/dir/file?args#fragments) seens bad to me. Maybe your app is doing this without you coded it. Think about fix this.

Anyway, what about merge 8080 and 80 tomcats and then add an apache as a front-end? Between apache and tomcat everythings is accessed on http://localhost!